# Bug between navigation screens and modal

Tags: react-native

So my problem is kind of weird,when i navigate between screens it seems to let the modal open but invisible.Lets say that i have a modal on my home page and pressing the menu button it opens the modal and i start navigate ,when i press the button again to open the modal and navigate to another screen it navigates but it lets open an invisible modal.

Anyone knows what kind of bug this is?

Code below :

```
export default function Header() {

  //Use of navigation Hook
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  //Modal Constructor
  const [modalVisible,setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  

    return (
  
    // Container
    <View style = {styles.Header}>

      {/* Modal    */}
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>

        <View style = {styles.modalStyle}>
          
          {/* Pressable and Text for each functionality  */}
          <Pressable  style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Home</Text>
          </Pressable>
            
          <Pressable  style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Profile</Text>
          </Pressable>
          
          <Pressable style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Settings</Text>
          </Pressable>  

          <Pressable style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('LogInPage')}>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Log Out</Text>
          </Pressable> 

          <Pressable onPress={ () => {setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}} style = {styles.pressable}>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Close modal</Text>
          </Pressable>

        </View>


      </Modal>

      {/* Pressable Mechanism in order to open the Modal */}
      <Pressable onPress={ () => {setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}} style = {styles.pressableMenu}>
        <SimpleLineIcons style = {styles.iconMenu} name="menu" size={Dimensions.get('window').width > 800 ? 40 : 24 } color="white" />
        <Text style = {styles.menuText}>Menu</Text>
      </Pressable>

      <Text style = {styles.nameText}> E-Library</Text>

    </View>
```

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal?

Comment: No,i made a custom modal myself from react native library.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a video of it? And does that happen when you press something specifically or does it only happen when you are using it the second time (what I assume from your question)?

Comment: Its just when i enter a navigate screen and return back to it only ,its like invisible modal.I go to the visible modal suppose to be (but it is invisible) and then i press a button on it and its working ..its so weird.How i can share video here ?